# Inline script variables undefined even though external scripts far above

Tags: javascript

On our webpage we've got a few external scripts to load things like Axios and Vue. Then much further down the page we've got inline scripts using those.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-promise/4.1.1/es6-promise.auto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

... 100 + lines of html later ...

<script type="text/javascript">
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
   axios.defaults.baseURL = 'blahblah';

   var app = new Vue({
      ...
   });
});
</script>
```

We're getting axios is undefined errors from a small number of users. We've tried to simulate their OS/Browser setup but we can't reproduce the error ourselves.

It was our understanding the external scripts should load first and the browser only runs the inline ones after all external ones have finished?

Any ideas?

jQuery 1.7 is loaded in the head tag long before this code. Move the external scripts into the head before jQuery doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Could some of the external scripts be failing to load?

Comment: Try asking them to navigate to `https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js` and see if they actually get a response, maybe a firewall or something on their network is blocking it.

Comment: The only reasons they'd be getting that are: 1. `https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js` fails to load for them. 2. Something else sets `axios` to `undefined` after it loads.

Comment: `from a small number of users` are any of them savvy enough to know what a developer tools console is?

Comment: Have asked a sofar helpful user to send me some console output. I assume perhaps hosting a copy of axios etc rather than using a CDN might help?

Comment: Sweet mother of mercy, she's getting Insecure Response errors! Going directly to unpkg gives her ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID!!? I can see they have a cert start date of 25/1/17 ...